# Notation-Linear Algebra/ Euclidean Geometry

Tags: linear-algebra, notation, euclidean-geometry

This is a notational question:

What does $\overset{\underset{\mathrm{\Delta }}{}}{=}$ denote in

$-0.5JDJ\overset{\underset{\mathrm{\Delta }}{}}{=} X^TX$ where $J=I-n^{-1}ee^T$ with $e$ being a vector of $1's$ and $D$ is a matrix of squared distances of the rows in $X$ i.e, $D_{ij}=||X_{i.}-X_{j.}||^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symbol usually means 'is defined as' or 'is another name for'. Do you see why that might make sense in your context?